# ¿Como saber cuando instrucciones ejecutadas con mysqli_multi_query ya terminaron de ejecutarse?

Tags: mysql

¿Como puedo saber cuando instrucciones ejecutadas con mysqli_multi_query ya terminaron de ejecutarse?

Tengo un pequeño código que ejecuta algunas instrucciones mysql, y luego se supone que cuando terminan ejecuto una instrucción simple para dar de alta un registro que se supone ya se borró, pero me indica que la llave está duplicada, lo que significa que en realidad no terminaron de ejecutarte antes de que mande ejecutar la última instruccion:

```
$sql="";
for ($i=0;$i<=mysqli_num_rows($Tsqlusuarios)-1;$i++)
{
    $RTsqlusuarios=mysqli_fetch_assoc($Tsqlusuarios);
    $sql=$sql."delete from UsuariosMedidas where idUsuario=".$RTsqlusuarios['IDUsuariosPrendas'].";";
    $sql=$sql."delete from articulosUsuarios where IDUsuariosPrendas=".$RTsqlusuarios['IDUsuariosPrendas'].";";
}

$sql=$sql."delete from cotizaciones where idcot=12504;";

//echo $sql;

if (mysqli_multi_query($enlace, $sql)) {
    //echo "Registros borrados";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($enlace);
}

if (!$Tsqlusuarios=mysqli_query($enlace,"INSERT INTO `cotizaciones` (idcot, vendedor, cliente,  lugar,   fecha, imagenes, paso,  status, observaciones,  `idprospectoOrigen`)
        VALUES
            ( 12504,3, 'CONSOLIDADO',  'GUADALAJARA',  '2011-09-20', 6, 3, 'CERRADA', NULL,  500000221);"))
{
    exit("Error description Z: " . mysqli_error($enlace));
}
```

Es en esta última instrucción donde me marca la fila duplicada cuando se supone que ya terminó de ejecutarse todo el comando mysqli_multi_query,
seguramente no entiendo como funciona esta función de instrucciones multiples y estoy mandando ejecutar codigo antes de verificar si realmente ya terminó. 
No sé como saberlo, ¿Alguna orientación?

Comment: [Revisa la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php), dice esto: *Devuelve FALSE si la primera sentencia falló. Para obtener el resto de errores de otras sentencias debe llamarse antes a `mysqli_next_result()`.* Allí mismo hay ejemplos de uso, se muestra un `while` en el cual se va llamando a `mysqli_next_result()`. El hecho es que te estás complicando la vida por no usar transacciones. Me parece que te lo sugerí antes en otra pregunta, si mal no recuerdo.

Comment: En este caso la sentencia no tiene error, el problema es que por alguna razón pareciera que la instrucción corre asíncrona.

Comment: Me parece que en algunos casos `multi_query` debe estar activado en el archivo de configuración de PHP. De todos modos puedes probar si está funcionando bien revisando (directamente en el manejador de la BD) si los registros a partir del segundo se están borrando realmente o no. En cualquier caso, optar por `multi_query` para esto me parece haber escogido el camino que parece corto, pero que es más largo por todas las limitaciones y complicaciones de esta función (esto es opinión mía). Además, asuntos importantes como la consistencia de datos no quedan asegurados.

Comment: El problema es que usar mysql_query que solo permite una sola instrucción causa que al usarlo en un "for" sea super lento el resultado del programa y que me corran del trabajo, de todas formas para poder usar las transacciones tengo que usar el multi_query si no ¿Cómo envío los comandos al servidor??? Igual se trata de un conjunto de instrucciones.

Comment: No estás obligado a usar `multi_query`. Como ya te dije en otra parte, los caminos más seguros para optimizar aquí son: 1. Usar consultas preparadas (lo cual te da dos ventajas: rapidez dado que el plan de consulta **se prepara una sola vez**; y seguridad, porque evitará ataques de *Inyección SQL*. 2. Usar transacciones, que también optimizan y aseguran la consistencia de datos, porque puedes revertir si algo falla. Si aún así el código sigue siendo lento tendrás que revisar otra cosas, como los índices de las tablas o la misma lógica,   tratando de resolver el problema de otro modo.